# JavaScript Canvas image processing library

Tags: library, javascript, image-processing

I've been working on a project that I forever could not complete because of something I don't know how to implement.

Does anyone know any image processing libraries (must use Canvas) that can allow me to specifically at least do the following:

- Add borders to drawn images
- Clip out parts of images
- <sup>**1**</sup>Resizing: Resizing just the image drawn and not the canvas element. (*scale to fit inside the canvas without ever stretching the image*)

  Like this but without the drag handling: http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html
- Mirror images
  in any of the four direction (flip/translation)

*<sup>**1**</sup>Some of these I can do. This is the main feature I am looking for.*

The reason I want a library at this time is because I'm tired of typing code. It's not laziness but rather too much work but that's off topic.

Thanks

Comment: UPDATE: Currently looking at fabric.js Looks like just what I need.